# jQuery lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I created a lightbox and it works fine. Now I want to create 2 lightboxes and I can't seems to get my jquery correct.

The 2 lightboxes are not displayed at the same time. There are 2 links that open each respectively.

```
<a href="#" class="lightbox1">Open box 1</a>
<a href="#" class="lightbox2">Open box 2</a>
```

There is a form in the first box and some content in the second.

HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="backdrop"></div> <--end of backdrop -->

<div id="wapper" class="centered">

<div class="box1">
<div class="close">x</div> <!--Close 'x' on the lightbox-->
<div class="clear"></div>  <!--CSS clear to correct flow -->
<form name="form1" id="form1">
...       
</form>
</div> <!--end of box1-->

<div class="box2">
<div class="close">x</div> <!--Close 'x' on the lightbox--> 
<div class="clear"></div> <!-- end of div clear -->
<div id="responce">
</div> <!-- end of div response [This is where the content goes after its fetched from mysql]-->
</div> <!-- end of box2 -->

</div><!--end of wapper -->

<style>
.backdrop
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:#000;
            opacity: .0;
            filter:alpha(opacity=0);
            z-index:50;
            display:none;
        }
        .box1, .box2
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:20%;
            left:30%;
            width:500px;
            height:300px;
            background:#ffffff;
            z-index:51;
            padding:10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
            display:none;
        }
        .close
        {
            float:right;
            margin-right:6px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
</style>
```

js/jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

              if ($('lightbox1').click(function()) {
         $('.backdrop,box1').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                    $('box1').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                    $('.backdrop, box1').css('display', 'block');

                 $('.close').click(function(){
                    close_box($('.box1'));
                  });

                  $('.backdrop').click(function(){
                    close_box($('.box1'));
                });
          }
          else if($('lightbox2').click(function()){
        $('.backdrop, box2').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                    $('box2').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                    $('.backdrop, box2').css('display', 'block');

                $('.close').click(function(){
                    close_box($('.box2'));
                });
           }
            });

            function close_box(box)
            {
                $('.backdrop, <box>').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                    $('.backdrop, <box>').css('display', 'none');
                });
            }
        </script>
```

I have been working on this code for 2 days now, trying to figure out whats wrong, can someone please help. The if condition is whats giving the issue. Also the close button is not working - how do I pass the parameter?

Thanks!

#

So, I was able to get the light box to work, jQuery/Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.lightbox1').click(
            function() {
                $('.backdrop, .box1').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.box1').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.backdrop, .box1').css('display', 'block');

                $('.close').click(function(){
                    close_box($(".box1"));
                });

                $('.backdrop').click(function(){
                    close_box($(".box1"));
                });
            });

            $('.lightbox2').click(
            function(){
                $('.backdrop, .box2').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.box2').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                $('.backdrop, .box2').css('display', 'block');

                $('.close').click(function(){
                    close_box($(".box2"));
                });
            });             

        });
```

The close_box() function is still not working. The parameter is not being passed in properly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused about your selector. You wouldn't use `$('<lightbox1>').click` but rather `$('.lightbox1').click` to select an element(s) which match(es) a class.

Same goes for `$('.backdrop, <box>')` in your `close_box()` function - I assume you want to use `box` as a variable, so you'd do `$('.backdrop, ' + box).animate(`

Comment: +1 I've never seen arrow tags used like that in a jQuery selector before.  This is a a good start, at least, towards solving your issue.

Comment: This is not my actual code, when I have a question I try to post a version of the code, not the whole file. The <> was where I was to put the handlers. I missed it in a couple of places. Sorry!

Also, with [$('.backdrop, ' + box).animate(] you answered part of my problem. Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to debug your code if it's not your actual code? Often times actual code has typos which never get passed along to the "example code" provided in the question. Just something to think about for future questions.

Comment: Well I am not too concerned about typos. I can figure that out. I just wanted to know if my logic or method of calling function in jQuery/Javascript is correct. And it is. It took me 2 days but I started with a clean sheet and I was able to get part of it to work.